# 3D picking lwjgl

Tags: opengl, 3d, lwjgl, picking

I have written some code to preform 3D picking that for some reason dosn't work entirely correct! (Im using LWJGL just so you know.)

This is how the code looks like:

```
if(Mouse.getEventButton() == 1) {
  if (!Mouse.getEventButtonState()) {
    Camera.get().generateViewMatrix();

    float screenSpaceX = ((Mouse.getX()/800f/2f)-1.0f)*Camera.get().getAspectRatio();
    float screenSpaceY = 1.0f-(2*((600-Mouse.getY())/600f));
    float displacementRate = (float)Math.tan(Camera.get().getFovy()/2);

    screenSpaceX *= displacementRate;
    screenSpaceY *= displacementRate;

    Vector4f cameraSpaceNear = new Vector4f((float) (screenSpaceX * Camera.get().getNear()), (float) (screenSpaceY * Camera.get().getNear()), (float) (-Camera.get().getNear()), 1);
    Vector4f cameraSpaceFar = new Vector4f((float) (screenSpaceX * Camera.get().getFar()), (float) (screenSpaceY * Camera.get().getFar()), (float) (-Camera.get().getFar()), 1);

    Matrix4f tmpView = new Matrix4f();
    Camera.get().getViewMatrix().transpose(tmpView);
    Matrix4f invertedViewMatrix = (Matrix4f)tmpView.invert();

    Vector4f worldSpaceNear = new Vector4f();
    Matrix4f.transform(invertedViewMatrix, cameraSpaceNear, worldSpaceNear);

    Vector4f worldSpaceFar = new Vector4f();
    Matrix4f.transform(invertedViewMatrix, cameraSpaceFar, worldSpaceFar);


    Vector3f rayPosition = new Vector3f(worldSpaceNear.x, worldSpaceNear.y, worldSpaceNear.z);
    Vector3f rayDirection = new Vector3f(worldSpaceFar.x - worldSpaceNear.x, worldSpaceFar.y - worldSpaceNear.y, worldSpaceFar.z - worldSpaceNear.z);

    rayDirection.normalise();

    Ray clickRay = new Ray(rayPosition, rayDirection);

    Vector tMin = new Vector(), tMax = new Vector(), tempPoint;
    float largestEnteringValue, smallestExitingValue, temp, closestEnteringValue = Camera.get().getFar()+0.1f;
    Drawable closestDrawableHit = null;
    for(Drawable d : this.worldModel.getDrawableThings()) {
        // Calcualte AABB for each object... needs to be moved later...
        firstVertex = true;
        for(Surface surface : d.getSurfaces()) {
            for(Vertex v : surface.getVertices()) {
                worldPosition.x = (v.x+d.getPosition().x)*d.getScale().x;
                worldPosition.y = (v.y+d.getPosition().y)*d.getScale().y;
                worldPosition.z = (v.z+d.getPosition().z)*d.getScale().z;
                worldPosition = worldPosition.rotate(d.getRotation());
                if (firstVertex) {
                    maxX = worldPosition.x; maxY = worldPosition.y; maxZ = worldPosition.z;
                    minX = worldPosition.x; minY = worldPosition.y; minZ = worldPosition.z;
                    firstVertex = false;
                } else {
                    if (worldPosition.x > maxX) {
                        maxX = worldPosition.x;
                    }
                    if (worldPosition.x < minX) {
                        minX = worldPosition.x;
                    }
                    if (worldPosition.y > maxY) {
                        maxY = worldPosition.y;
                    }
                    if (worldPosition.y < minY) {
                        minY = worldPosition.y;
                    }
                    if (worldPosition.z > maxZ) {
                        maxZ = worldPosition.z;
                    }
                    if (worldPosition.z < minZ) {
                        minZ = worldPosition.z;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // ray/slabs intersection test...


        // clickRay.getOrigin().x + clickRay.getDirection().x * f = minX
        // clickRay.getOrigin().x - minX = -clickRay.getDirection().x * f
        // clickRay.getOrigin().x/-clickRay.getDirection().x - minX/-clickRay.getDirection().x = f
        // -clickRay.getOrigin().x/clickRay.getDirection().x + minX/clickRay.getDirection().x = f


        largestEnteringValue = -clickRay.getOrigin().x/clickRay.getDirection().x + minX/clickRay.getDirection().x;
        temp = -clickRay.getOrigin().y/clickRay.getDirection().y + minY/clickRay.getDirection().y;
        if(largestEnteringValue < temp) {
            largestEnteringValue = temp;
        }
        temp = -clickRay.getOrigin().z/clickRay.getDirection().z + minZ/clickRay.getDirection().z;
        if(largestEnteringValue < temp) {
            largestEnteringValue = temp;
        }

        smallestExitingValue = -clickRay.getOrigin().x/clickRay.getDirection().x + maxX/clickRay.getDirection().x;
        temp = -clickRay.getOrigin().y/clickRay.getDirection().y + maxY/clickRay.getDirection().y;
        if(smallestExitingValue > temp) {
            smallestExitingValue = temp;
        }
        temp = -clickRay.getOrigin().z/clickRay.getDirection().z + maxZ/clickRay.getDirection().z;
        if(smallestExitingValue < temp) {
            smallestExitingValue = temp;
        }


            if(largestEnteringValue > smallestExitingValue) {
                //System.out.println("Miss!");
            } else {
                if (largestEnteringValue < closestEnteringValue) {
                    closestEnteringValue = largestEnteringValue;
                    closestDrawableHit = d;
                }
            }

    }
    if(closestDrawableHit != null) {
        System.out.println("Hit at: (" + clickRay.setDistance(closestEnteringValue).x + ", " + clickRay.getCurrentPosition().y + ", " + clickRay.getCurrentPosition().z);
        this.worldModel.removeDrawableThing(closestDrawableHit);    
    }
  }
}
```

I just don't understand what's wrong, the ray are shooting and i do hit stuff that gets removed but the result of the ray are verry strange it sometimes removes the thing im clicking at, sometimes it removes things thats not even close to what im clicking at, and sometimes it removes nothing at all.

**Edit:**

Okay so i have continued searching for errors and by debugging the ray (by painting smal dots where it travles) i can now se that there is something oviously wrong with the ray that im sending out... it has its origin near the world center and always shots to the same position no matter where i direct my camera...

My initial toughts is that there might be some error in the way i calculate my viewMatrix (since it's not possible to get the viewmatrix from the glulookat method in lwjgl; I have to build it my self and I guess thats where the problem is at)...

**Edit2:**

This is how i calculate it currently:

```
private double[][] viewMatrixDouble = {{0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,1}};

public Vector getCameraDirectionVector() {
    Vector actualEye = this.getActualEyePosition();
    return new Vector(lookAt.x-actualEye.x, lookAt.y-actualEye.y, lookAt.z-actualEye.z);
}

public Vector getActualEyePosition() {
    return eye.rotate(this.getRotation());
}

public void generateViewMatrix() {

    Vector cameraDirectionVector = getCameraDirectionVector().normalize();
    Vector side = Vector.cross(cameraDirectionVector, this.upVector).normalize();
    Vector up = Vector.cross(side, cameraDirectionVector);

    viewMatrixDouble[0][0] = side.x;                    viewMatrixDouble[0][1] = up.x;                  viewMatrixDouble[0][2] = -cameraDirectionVector.x;                 
    viewMatrixDouble[1][0] = side.y;                    viewMatrixDouble[1][1] = up.y;                  viewMatrixDouble[1][2] = -cameraDirectionVector.y;                 
    viewMatrixDouble[2][0] = side.z;                    viewMatrixDouble[2][1] = up.z;                  viewMatrixDouble[2][2] = -cameraDirectionVector.z;                 


    /*
    Vector actualEyePosition = this.getActualEyePosition();
    Vector zaxis = new Vector(this.lookAt.x - actualEyePosition.x, this.lookAt.y - actualEyePosition.y, this.lookAt.z - actualEyePosition.z).normalize();
    Vector xaxis = Vector.cross(upVector, zaxis).normalize();
    Vector yaxis = Vector.cross(zaxis, xaxis);
    viewMatrixDouble[0][0] = xaxis.x;                   viewMatrixDouble[0][1] = yaxis.x;                   viewMatrixDouble[0][2] = zaxis.x;                  
    viewMatrixDouble[1][0] = xaxis.y;                   viewMatrixDouble[1][1] = yaxis.y;                   viewMatrixDouble[1][2] = zaxis.y;                  
    viewMatrixDouble[2][0] = xaxis.z;                   viewMatrixDouble[2][1] = yaxis.z;                   viewMatrixDouble[2][2] = zaxis.z;                  
    viewMatrixDouble[3][0] = -Vector.dot(xaxis, actualEyePosition); viewMatrixDouble[3][1] =-Vector.dot(yaxis, actualEyePosition);  viewMatrixDouble[3][2] = -Vector.dot(zaxis, actualEyePosition);
    */
    viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    viewMatrix.load(getViewMatrixAsFloatBuffer());
}
```

Would be verry greatfull if anyone could verify if this is wrong or right, and if it's wrong; supply me with the right way of doing it...
I have read alot of threads and documentations about this but i can't seam to wrapp my head around it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i finaly solved it with the help from the guys at gamedev and a friend, here is a link to the [answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/21964/12311) where i have posted the code!

Answer (score 0):

> I just don't understand what's wrong, the ray are shooting and i do hit stuff that gets removed but things are not disappearing where i press on the screen.

OpenGL is not a scene graph, it's a drawing library. So after removing something from your internal representation you must redraw the scene. And your code is missing some call to a function that triggers a redraw.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am sorry if i was a bit unclear but that is not my entire program, just the part which handles the 3D Picking (which lies in the world controller). The rendering of the scene is done in a separate part of the program (in the world view).
I can se the result of the objects that are removed but for some reason its removing the wrong objects.